# passing an element with an event listener to appendChild inside template event

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor client code failed to fire the `mousemove` event on the canvas created in the public method. `onmousemove` also failed.
Can this be done and if so, how?

```js
Template.report.events({
    'click #myElemnt': functionj(event) {
        event.target.appendChild(lib.myCanvas());
    }
})

//lib.js
lib = (function() {

    return {
        myCanvas: () => {

            let canv = document.createElement('canvas');
            //style it here
            canv.addEventListener('onmousemove', function() {
                console.log('moving');
            }
            return canv;
        }

    })();
```

**edit**
Here is the part of the code after changing the syntax

```js
lib = (function() {

      return {

        myCanvas: () => {
          let sigCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          sigCanvas.style.position = 'absolute';
          sigCanvas.style.width = 25 + 'em';
          sigCanvas.style.height = 15 + 'em';
          sigCanvas.style.top = -90 + 'px';
          sigCanvas.style.left = -50 + 'px';
          sigCanvas.id = 'signature';
          sigCanvas.style.border = '1px solid black';

          sigCanvas.addEventListener('onmousemove', function() {
            console.log('mouse moving again');
          }, false);
          return sigCanvas;
        }
      }());
```

**edit2**
here is the canvas from the browser element tab
[image]

Comment: There seems syntax error in the code, attach the event listener like this.

 canv.addEventListener('onmousemove', function() {
                console.log('moving');
            }, false);

try this once.

Comment: @VishalGupta that did not fire the `onmousemove` still

Comment: I have done a lot of stuff like that in jQuery, should I mention those.?

Comment: You obviously simplified your code (as the posted version does contains a syntax error). If you changed the code to correct the syntax error, please post the valid code. And why did you wrap your lib with a IIFE?

Comment: @MasterAM the reason of IIFE is to keep the namespace clean as it has many other public and private methods. I will post the valid code after changing the syntax

Comment: @VishalGupta yes, you can try jQuery. thx

Comment: Your code is not sufficient for reproducing what you experienced. Without a proper reproduction, it is very difficult to determine what went wrong in your case, since implementing a (slightly corrected) version of the code you supplied seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should supply the event type without an `on` prefix to the `addEventListener` method, as per the [`EventTarget` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

This should do the work:

```
sigCanvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  console.log('mouse moving again');
});
```

Comment: Please notice in my post that I already tried this, however I tried it again as per your answer for no avail.

Comment: Nonetheless, this is the correct form. `onmousemove` will not work. Try to isolate your issue. Create a `canvas` in the console and append it to the body. Try to style it as you do in the library and see if that changes its behavior. Then inspect the canvas created by your code and see what listeners it has and manipulate it using the console. Your code simply does not suffice for reproduction.

Comment: the event works if it is attached to the Meteor template, I might be that Blaze is not happy with middle man event.

Comment: No reason for this to happen. If you created a DOM element and attached an event handler to it, Blaze will not intervene if the template does not re-render. I would appreciate a very simple reproduction.